# How to make a input instead of putting number in field

Tags: java, system.out

I have a set number of 456 where it reads out how many digits it has. So the program when ran would say "3". I wanna make it where I have a input to just enter a number. It seems so simple and I came this far, but I can't figure it out. Please help I would appreciate you sooo much.

```java
package recursion;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class recursiontest {

    //adding the scanner
    Scanner b = new Scanner (System.in);

    public static int digitCounted(int number) {

        //starting
        if (number == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        return 1 + digitCounted(number/10);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int number = 456;
        int result = digitCounted(number);
        System.out.println("Number of digits in the number is: " + result);

    }
}
```

I can't figure this out.

Comment: Have you try to use the Scanner? It seems that you still not using it.

Comment: [`int number = b.nextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt())

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use your Scanner.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class recursiontest {

    public static int digitCounted(int number) {
        if (number == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        return 1 + digitCounted(number/10);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int number, result;

        System.out.print("Please enter the number: ");
        number = sc.nextInt();

        result = digitCounted(number);
        System.out.println("Number of digits in the number is: " + result);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am so angry at myself, that I couldn't solve a simple mistake. Thank you so much.

Comment: @smoknovo Your welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer if it's anwering your question. Welcome to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you are looking for

```
import java.util.*;    
public class Main
{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("First input number digits "+ takeInput());
            System.out.println("Second input number digits "+ takeInput());
        }

    public static int takeInput() {
      Scanner scanner= new Scanner(System.in);
      int input =  scanner.nextInt();
      return (input+"").length();
    }
}
```